# prevent youtube video artifacts showing after video overlay closes

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm putting video's in an overlay that I show when a user clicks the video thumbnail.
I use the iframe youtube api.
When the user closes the overlay, I stopVideo the video and the overlay closes. However, when you mouse over the parts of the screen where the video was, artifacts from the last frame of the video start to appear at random (tested in Chrome).

I've tried hiding the iframe, moving it off-screen etc etc. The only thing that seems to work is to physically remove the player iframe from the overlay. That's one way forward, but a nicer one would be to prevent the artifacts in the first place any ideas?